# How do I get some USB devices to be recognised when I plug them in rather than only on boot?

Tags: usb, input-devices, tty

I have a number of USB devices (including a USB external HD) which will only be recognised by Ubuntu during boot.

For example:

If I plug in an RS232 device using a serial->USB device THEN boot Ubuntu /dev/ttyUSB0 is generated. However if I plug it in once Ubuntu is already booted, I don't get any /dev/ttyUSB0 until I reboot.

This is pretty annoying; is there anything I can run to get this to work?

Comment: Most USB devices _are_ hot-pluggable and will be detected by Ubuntu when you plug them and the computer is already on.  So, I would look for errors of some kind.  For a start, can you run `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` and post the lines that appear when you plug in/out a device that only works at boot?

Comment: That sounds like a bug really...

Comment: Please file a bug about this - it seems like this is a bug specific to this device. (My RS232-USB adapter gives me a /dev/ttyUSB0 upon its insertion, although I have not tried it on 10.10.)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).